# Use fallback DNS on iOS (Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a DNS problem in some internet providers in my country and the host configured in my app is not found.

For that, in ANDROID, I found a solution by adding a property in the Java VM.

```
protected void init() { 
    System.setProperty("dns.server", "8.8.8.8");
    super.init(); 
}
```

Is there any similar solution for iOS? Mainly using objective-c? I didn't find anything searching on google.

Comment: Because of the heavily-sandboxed nature of iOS, there's no simple way of doing this. You'll probably want to look into the DNS proxy services in the NetworkExtension framework. It's not going to be a one-liner like on Android, though.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/dns_proxy_provider?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using a command-line tool as an API is generally a bad idea, even more so when there’s a full-featured public API behind that tool.

As to why you’re seeing different behaviour with

```
networksetup
```

, that’s a surprisingly complex issue. The tool calls SystemConfiguration framework, which uses Authorisation Services to authorise the operation (see the discussion around

```
SCPreferencesCreateWithAuthorization
```

). Authorization Services is rather complex, but one of its features is the ability to use an existing credential to satisfy a new authorisation request. Back in the day I wrote a Q&A to explain the ins’n’outs of this (QA1277 Security Credentials) but to this day I’m not 100% sure I got it right